# ebay API "getTopSellingProducts" returns the products that are not available

Tags: coldfusion, e-commerce, product, ebay-api

I am working with the ebay API and have a call to [getTopSellingProducts](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/getTopSellingProducts.html?rmvSB=true). The products are successfully retrieved, but when I visit the product URL the details are given but it is not currently available on ebay. If it is not available then how is it a top selling product?

[image: Dump of API Response]

The product on ebay is
[image: Product URL on ebay]

Comment: Not familiar with the API, but .. would assume the obvious - it is a top seller that happens to be sold out or unavailable at moment. Sounds like your real question is something else, like "how can you exclude them?". Might want to [edit] your question to elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that many of the items retrieved aren't available to be shipped to your geographical location, so they appear as unavailable when you, the developer, attempt to view the item on eBay.com.